# How to work with inside(V) and outside(U) vectors of wordtovec model?

Tags: deep-learning, word2vec, word-embeddings

In word to vec module each word has two vectors inside and out side. Or when the word belongs to the context word and when the word belongs to the center word. In the end do we normalize those vectors by adding them up or we just take the inside vectors(Vc)?